# Lua set cooldown for reload

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

I have this set in my lua reload section and I'd love to set a cooldown function for it like how there is for primaryfire and secondary fire. Is there anyway to do that? Here's my code.

```
function SWEP:Reload()
    if Chaos == 0 then
        Chaos = 1
        self.Owner:SetModel("models/_tails_ models/characters/sonic heroes/super_sonic/supersonic.mdl")
        self.Weapon:EmitSound( "weapons/now.wav" )
    elseif Chaos == 1 then
        Chaos = 0
        self.Owner:SetModel("models/_tails_ models/characters/sonic heroes/sonic/sonic.mdl")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`os.time()` should do the trick.
You can take a look at the [documentation](http://www.lua.org/pil/22.1.html) at the Lua website.

The logic behind allowing something to happen only after *sometime* is to check the time elapsed since the last time the function was used.
Logically, it would be -

```
timeElapsed = lastTimeOfUse - timeNow
```

If `timeElapsed > cooldownPeriod` then allow the event to take place and set the `lastTimeOfUse = timeNow`.

---

If you mean something like reload function will work only after **60** *(change it to anything)* seconds, try the following :-

```
-- Settings
cooldown = 60 -- Cooldown period in Seconds

-- Reload function with cooldown
local lastReloadTime=0;
function SWEP:Reload()
    if ((os.time()-lastReloadTime)>cooldown) then -- Allows only after cooldown time is over
        if Chaos == 0 then
            Chaos = 1
            self.Owner:SetModel("models/_tails_ models/characters/sonic heroes/super_sonic/supersonic.mdl")
            self.Weapon:EmitSound( "weapons/now.wav" )
        elseif Chaos == 1 then
            Chaos = 0
            self.Owner:SetModel("models/_tails_ models/characters/sonic heroes/sonic/sonic.mdl")
        end
        lastReloadTime=os.time() -- Sets this time as last using time of Reload
    end
end
```

---

Based on your comment, if you want to loop the sound till a specific time, something like this should work

```
 -- Settings
durationOfPlayback = 3 -- for how long you want to play the sound in seconds

-- Specifications
durationOfSoundFile = 1 -- length of sound file in seconds

-- Sound playback for a specific time cooldown
noOfTimesToPlay = math.floor(durationOfPlayback/durationOfSoundFile)
function SWEP:Reload()
    ...
    for i = 1, noOfTimesToPlay do
    {
            self.Weapon:EmitSound( "weapons/now.wav" )
            lastSoundTime=os.time()

            --This line will make the loop wait till 1 playback is complete
            while((os.time()-lastSoundTime)<durationOfSoundFile) do end
    }
    ...
end
```

Comment: I'm sorry for any confusion I was in abit of rush. But, I edited my   question for what I meant. I'll post it here too.

"What I mean is like is there a way I can set a timer for the emitsound part, sorry for any confusion." 

Actually what you provided may be just what I need, but might as well ask since I'm curious. Is there anyway to set a timer on the self.weapon:emitsound part.

Comment: Disregard all I've said that worked! Thanks alot man! I really appreciate it :)

Comment: Yep, then you would have to use the same technique for the emit sound part too, using another variable called lastSoundTime maybe, and looping it till the cool-down period is over. Let me try to edit my reply.

You are most welcome :) Keep up the great work and put down your imagination.

Comment: Idk where my other comment went so I'll just sum up what I said. 

Thanks alot dude! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me.